# How to perform doubleclick?

Tags: c#, winapi, mouse

I know, there are a lot of questions like this. But every answer i read, did not helped me.. So i ask here.

I want to perform a mouse double click. Before that i have already set the cursor to the correct position:

```
  Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(2225, 154);
```

I already used almost every class i found here, and no one helped me. (The cursor was set, but no double click were performed..)

Hope anyone can help me. Thanks!

Greets

edit: 
the class i used:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AutoClicker
{

    public class MouseSimulator
    {

      public void test_Click(System.Drawing.Point p)
           {
            //Move the mouse to the button position

            //Perform button click.
            INPUT structInput = new INPUT();
            structInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
            structInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.ABSOLUTE | MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN | MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP;
            structInput.mkhi.mi.dx = p.X;
            structInput.mkhi.mi.dy = p.Y;
            uint i = SendInput(1, ref structInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

        [Flags]
        public enum MouseEventFlags
        {
            LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
            LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
            MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
            MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
            MOVE = 0x00000001,
            ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
            RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
            RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The event type contained in the union field
        /// </summary>
        enum SendInputEventType : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Contains Mouse event data
            /// </summary>
            InputMouse,
            /// <summary>
            /// Contains Keyboard event data
            /// </summary>
            InputKeyboard,
            /// <summary>
            /// Contains Hardware event data
            /// </summary>
            InputHardware
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// The mouse data structure
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct MouseInputData
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The x value, if ABSOLUTE is passed in the flag then this is an actual X and Y value
            /// otherwise it is a delta from the last position
            /// </summary>
            public int dx;
            /// <summary>
            /// The y value, if ABSOLUTE is passed in the flag then this is an actual X and Y value
            /// otherwise it is a delta from the last position
            /// </summary>
            public int dy;
            /// <summary>
            /// Wheel event data, X buttons
            /// </summary>
            public uint mouseData;
            /// <summary>
            /// ORable field with the various flags about buttons and nature of event
            /// </summary>
            public MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
            /// <summary>
            /// The timestamp for the event, if zero then the system will provide
            /// </summary>
            public uint time;
            /// <summary>
            /// Additional data obtained by calling app via GetMessageExtraInfo
            /// </summary>
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct KEYBDINPUT
        {
            public ushort wVk;
            public ushort wScan;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct HARDWAREINPUT
        {
            public int uMsg;
            public short wParamL;
            public short wParamH;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures the union of the three three structures.
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        struct MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The Mouse Input Data
            /// </summary>
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public MouseInputData mi;

            /// <summary>
            /// The Keyboard input data
            /// </summary>
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public KEYBDINPUT ki;

            /// <summary>
            /// The hardware input data
            /// </summary>
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Data passed to SendInput in an array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Contains a union field type specifies what it contains </remarks>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct INPUT
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The actual data type contained in the union Field
            /// </summary>
            public SendInputEventType type;
            public MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion mkhi;
        }
    }

}
```

and i used it like this:

```
System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(2225, 154);
        Cursor.Position = p;
        MouseSimulator ms = new MouseSimulator();
        ms.test_Click(p);
```

Comment: The code you showed only shows that you're changing the position, how are you performing your double click? How did you try to?

Comment: Use SendInput().  A double-click is generated when you have the button go up and down twice in a short time and the app is willing to recognize it.

Comment: I've added the class i use and the way i used.

Comment: A double click requires 4 input events. Mouse down, up, down, up. You send 1. Any reason why you rejected UI Automation? This sort of question is asked many times every day. Gets a little wearing after a while.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan nothing happens anyway if i do it twice.

Comment: Down, up, down up. That's four events. You send just 1. And the one you send has both down and up flags. So that won't work. I'd expect the function call to fail, but you don't check for errors so you've no idea whether or not the call to `SendInput` succeeds. I suggest that you spend some more time with the documentation. And once again. Why did you reject UI Automation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need ti simulate the double click, you need to send 4 `INPUT` using `SendInput()`:

```
public void test_Click(System.Drawing.Point p) {
    //Move the mouse to the button position

    //Perform button click.
    INPUT down = new INPUT();
    down.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
    down.mkhi.mi.dx = p.X;
    down.mkhi.mi.dy = p.Y;
    down.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN;

    INPUT up = new INPUT();
    up.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
    up.mkhi.mi.dx = p.X;
    up.mkhi.mi.dy = p.Y;
    up.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP;

    INPUT[] dbl = {down, up, down, up};

    SendInput(4, dbl, Marshal.SizeOf(down));
}
```

Also, define `SendInput()` as follows:

```
static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Revised. Just tried to make a simple hotfix :p